# NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat can't reference superView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

Here's some code:

```
UIView *c = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self addSubview:c];
c.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
c. backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[c(>=600)]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(c)]] ;
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[c]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(c)]] ;![enter image description here][1]
```

Why does it end up looking like this? Is something messed up with my superView?

[image: Image of messed constraint]]

Here's how my containing view is setup:
[image: IB setup of containing view]

Comment: What are we looking at in this image? I see a blue outline, a green rectangle and a gray rounded rect. Which of these objects is the view where the code above is (i.e. what is self)?

Comment: I copied the code you have now, and I got a gray view that's full height and 20 points from the left and right edge (the >=600 doesn't do anything though -- it's the same without it). Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, totally that's what I want. The light gray box is the view I'm adding constraints to. The blue outlined box is the superview of that view which is self. What could be affecting self that stops that constraint code from working?

Comment: What is the blue outlined box? Is that one view, or a dark blue view with a lighter blue view on top? What is self?

Comment: Self is blue outlined box. It's one view with border.

Comment: The constraints look right, but I don't understand the x and y coordinates of that view. Why aren't they both 0? Also, I'll ask again, what is self in your code? Is it your controller's view?

Comment: x&y aren't zero because he's set the origin for the view to centre.

Answer (score 0):

The superview of `c` is `self`. Not `self.superview`.

So those lines should read:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[c]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(c)]] ;
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[c]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(c)]] ;
```

Also the designated initialiser for UIView is `-initWithFrame:` just calling `init` isn't guaranteed to work. So that first line should be

```
UIView *c = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Also, the 0's in "V:|-0-[c]-0-|" are unnecessary it should be written "V:|[c]|"

Comment: Sorry, calling self.superview was actually debug code. I'm updating my post with the original code. I've also switched out to CGRectZero. Still not working

Comment: The top and left constraints are working as expected.  And if this is a copy/paste and c is really a UIView, then it has no intrinsic size that would stop it sizing properly. So I suspect that the problem is in the containing view. In code you haven't given us. What is the containing view? How is it sized?  Is it the green view in the picture? Is there only one view that's coloured green?

Comment: Yup containing view is the green background blue outline view. Something is wrong with that view. It's set up in IB. I'll add images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's now looking like the constraint failure was because the view that held everything was a subclass of UIScrollView.